# How to debug jQuery UI effect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, debugging

I am using the jQuery UI library for the [shake effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/). On my website, it works as expected for certain elements, but not for image elements within a d3.js canvas, for these images it just causes them to flicker. I suspect this may be because of other tags or attributes on these elements, but I have no idea how to begin debugging this issue?

Should I use a JavaScript debugger, or try to disable certain attributes of these images? This is a pretty mysterious and frustrating bug, and I need some advice on how to fix it.

Comment: Id' try to recreate using just the UI code and a single image element. I'd guess there is limited support for jquery UI on svg image elements, but a simple test with a single image and the UI code should confirm it. I wouldn't expect it to be an error, so the debugger might not be much help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to get info what are the styles of element and wrapper created by jQuery UI during animation - using developer tools / firebug.

For example by running something like that from console (when toggle is id of animated element):

```
setInterval(function() { 
    if (jQuery('.ui-effects-wrapper').length > 0) { 
        console.log(jQuery('.ui-effects-wrapper').get(0).style);
        console.log(jQuery('#toggle').get(0).style);
    }
},10);
```

Or something more complex with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for maybe more frequent dump.

This might give understanding what happens.